# Native ads in a firebase recylerview activity

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview, native-ads

This is the Activity for showing items in a recyclerview from a firebase database. In the activity I also have put my Native ad code, but my ads are not showing after every 5 items properly. Ads are always been loading one by one with in few seconds after every cardviews in a recyclerview.

Please help me in resolving the issue, I want my ads to be shown in my recyclerview properly with the code I show below.

```
public class HOME_RV_BUS_ACTIVITY extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText inputSearch;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BusModel> options;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BusModel,BusViewHolder> adapter;
DatabaseReference Dataref;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // To remove status Bar
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home__rv__bus__activity);



    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);



    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);   //To show back arrow
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_black_keyboard_arrow);//customize my own back arrow color
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#000000\">" + "List Of InterCity Buses" +"</font>")); //change title on your own choice and also change it's color also


    Dataref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bus");


    inputSearch = findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



    LoadData("");

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString()!=null)
            {
                LoadData(s.toString());
            }
            else
            {
                LoadData("");
            }



        }
    });




}//onCreate end




private void LoadData(String data) {

    Query query=Dataref.orderByChild("BusName").startAt(data).endAt(data+"\uf8ff");

    options=new  FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BusModel>().setQuery(query,BusModel.class).build();
    adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BusModel, BusViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BusViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull BusModel model) {



            /////////////////////NativeAd////////////////////////////

   /* MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {*/

            if (position % 5 == 0) {

                AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(HOME_RV_BUS_ACTIVITY.this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110");
                builder.forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd nativeAd) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "OnNativeAdLoaded");

                        if (isDestroyed()) {
                            nativeAd.destroy();
                            return;
                        }

                        NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();
                        TemplateView template = findViewById(R.id.my_template);
                        template.setStyles(styles);
                        template.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        template.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
                    }
                });
                builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                    }
                });
                builder.withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                        // used here to specify individual options settings.
                        .build());
                AdLoader adLoader = builder
                        .build();
                adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


                holder.templateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

       /* }
    });*/


///////////////////////Native Ad End////////////////////


                holder.textView.setText(model.getBusName());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
                holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(HOME_RV_BUS_ACTIVITY.this, BusPicViewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("BusKey", getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public BusViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_view_bus,parent,false);
                return new BusViewHolder(v);
            }
        };
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is the Model Class

```
public class BusModel {

    private String BusName;
    private String ImageUrl;

public BusModel(String busName, String imageUrl) {
    BusName = busName;
    ImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public BusModel() {
}

public String getBusName() {
    return BusName;
}

public void setBusName(String busName) {
    BusName = busName;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return ImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    ImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
}
```

This is the ViewHolder where I also have put Ad Template view

```
 public class BusViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
    View v;

    TemplateView templateView;


public BusViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_single_view);
    textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_single_view);
    templateView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_template);

    v = itemView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

myviewholde.adlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

```
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        myviewholde.adlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(myviewholde.button_down.getContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110");
        builder.forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd nativeAd) {
                Log.d("TAG", "OnNativeAdLoaded");

                NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                        NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();
                TemplateView template =myviewholde.templateView.findViewById(R.id.id_ad_template_view);
                template.setStyles(styles);
                template.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                template.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
            }
        });
        builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
            }
        });
        builder.withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                // used here to specify individual options settings.
                .build());
        AdLoader adLoader = builder
                .build();
        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


        myviewholde.templateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

1.put your adview in layout and make it invisble
2.and you need to learn recyleview concept recyleview does not create new views
that why you are seeing your load one by one